# Haskell Find Perfect Squares -- getting type errors

Tags: haskell, types, casting, functional-programming

I just started learning haskell, and I tried to implement a simple function to check if a number is a square root. I think I'm having some issues understanding the Haskell type system -- my only other programming experience is ruby and some Java. This is what I had so far (Sorry if its really stupid):

```
isPerfectSquare :: (RealFloat t) => t -> Bool
isPerfectSquare n = 
    (sqrt n) == (truncate (sqrt n))
```

This is what i would do in ruby ... But here it gives me this error:

```
Could not deduce (Integral t) arising from a use of `truncate'
from the context (RealFloat t)
  bound by the type signature for
             isPerfectSquare :: RealFloat t => t -> Bool
  at more.hs:(73,1)-(74,35)
Possible fix:
  add (Integral t) to the context of
    the type signature for isPerfectSquare :: RealFloat t => t -> Bool
In the second argument of `(==)', namely `(truncate (sqrt n))'
In the expression: (sqrt n) == (truncate (sqrt n))
In an equation for `isPerfectSquare':
    isPerfectSquare n = (sqrt n) == (truncate (sqrt n))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Could you please explain what the problem is, how to fix it, and preferably any basic concepts I am not understanding? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sqrt has type:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

truncate has type:

```
truncate :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

In other words, sqrt returns a floating-point number, while truncate returns an integer. You have to insert an explicit conversion. In this case, you probably want `fromIntegral`, which can convert any integral type to any numeric type:

```
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b
```

You can then make the comparison:

```
(sqrt n) == (fromIntegral $ truncate (sqrt n))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I guess I just have a lot to learn.